# Dropzone event handling not giving any life sign

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

i'm using dropzone to build an interface to an online storage api, for uploading files. I've to upload multiple files and to make an ajax call everytime a file is uploaded so that an input field of the hidden form below get added. It's not a big deal for itself, i just have to add a call to the init property of dropzone (i'm not creating a custo dropzone, i'm just using the default one). So at line 1581 i wrote:

```
  Dropzone.options = {
      init: function() {
            this.on("addedfile", function(file) { alert("added file"); });
          }
```

};

but when i add i file to the dropzone nothing happens.
I'm processing multiple files, so am I calling the wrong event? maybe should i call successmultiple? [this](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) is the dropzone tutorial. Any idea?

Comment: do you mean that you are modifing the plugin code directly?

Comment: yes is this the right place to do it?

Comment: nop, you shouldnt touch the code of the plugin

Comment: i think maybe i have to write code directly into the ajax call

Comment: take a look at the answer

Answer (score 1):

if you have a form, with an id="my-awesome-dropzone" like in the example

```
<form action="/file-upload"
      class="dropzone"
      id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

You have to create a config object in the same document, i.e. in the header

```
<script src="./path/to/dropzone.js"></script>

<script >
//"myAwesomeDropzone" is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID

Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) { alert("Added file."); });
  }
};

</script>
```

If instead of this, you are creating the dropzone by

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("form.myFormClass"); //or something like this
```

you have to add the options as the second parameter

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("form.myFormClass", {
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) { alert("Added file."); });
  }
});
```

Comment: I wrote `id="my-awesome-dropzone"´ but the code is not displayed in the page source, it's like javascript is overwriting it, and the script is not executed.

Comment: but you was creating the dropzone by `var myDropzone = new Dropzone("myform");` or how?